# Dependency problem deploying .NET Core application to Server 2012

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly, assembly-loading

I'm developing a web application in C#, Visual Studio 15.8.4, using Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.4. I am trying to deploy on Windows Server 2012.  I am experiencing the following error on the server side:

```
PS C:\inetpub\wwwroot\CustomsInvoice> dotnet .\CustomsInvoice.dll
Error:
  An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest 
(CustomsInvoice.deps.json) was not found:
    package: 'System.Xml.XPath.XmlDocument', version: '4.3.0'
    path: 'lib/netstandard1.3/System.Xml.XPath.XmlDocument.dll'
```

I have the following SDK and runtimes installed:

```
PS C:\inetpub\wwwroot\CustomsInvoice> dotnet --info
.NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   2.1.400
 Commit:    8642e60a0f

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  6.2.9200
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win8-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.400\

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 2.1.4
  Commit:  85255dde3e

.NET Core SDKs installed:
  2.1.400 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

.NET Core runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.2 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.4 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.2 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.4 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.0.9 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.2 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.4 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
```

I have included `System.Xml.XPath.XmlDocument v4.3.0` and `System.Xml.XPath v4.3.0` nuget packages in my project.

I suspect that there's a clue in the reference to the `lib/netstandard1.3` path in the error message, but I'm not experienced enough to interpret what it is trying to tell me.

Anyone have any ideas? Would any additional information be helpful in diagnosing this error?

Comment: Have you tried running `dotnet restore`?

Comment: Visual Studio runs restore on each build AFAIK.

Comment: How did you publish?

Comment: Hello - I used a folder profile to deploy.  Created a .zip file from the folder (../bin/Release/netcoreapp2.1/publish/), ftp'd to the server and unzipped into the target directory.